# Slow MySQL query, row 1 "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort." seems to be the issue

Tags: mysql, performance, entity-attribute-value

How can I improve the performance of this explain plan?

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
    wp_posts.ID
FROM
    wp_posts
        INNER JOIN
    wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
        INNER JOIN
    wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id)
        INNER JOIN
    wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id)
WHERE
    1 = 1
        AND ((wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'jobsearch_field_job_publish_date'
        AND wp_postmeta.meta_value <= '1593110936')
        AND (mt1.meta_key = 'jobsearch_field_job_expiry_date'
        AND mt1.meta_value >= '1593110936')
        AND (mt2.meta_key = 'jobsearch_field_job_status'
        AND mt2.meta_value = 'approved'))
        AND wp_posts.post_type = 'job'
        AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0 , 1;
```

Output:

```
*** row 1 ***
          table:  mt2
           type:  ref
  possible_keys:  post_id,meta_key
            key:  meta_key
        key_len:  767
            ref:  const
           rows:  31148
          ***Extra:  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort***
*** row 2 ***
          table:  wp_posts
           type:  eq_ref
  possible_keys:  PRIMARY,type_status_date
            key:  PRIMARY
        key_len:  8
            ref:  joborus.mt2.post_id
           rows:  1
          Extra:  Using where
*** row 3 ***
          table:  wp_postmeta
           type:  ref
  possible_keys:  post_id,meta_key
            key:  post_id
        key_len:  8
            ref:  joborus.mt2.post_id
           rows:  120
          Extra:  Using where
*** row 4 ***
          table:  mt1
           type:  ref
  possible_keys:  post_id,meta_key
            key:  post_id
        key_len:  8
            ref:  joborus.mt2.post_id
           rows:  120
          Extra:  Using where
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess what -- there are probably *two* sorts!  One for the `GROUP BY`, one for the `ORDER BY`.  `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` will clarify that.

If your question is about performance, then blame the basic design pattern called "Entity-Attribute-Value" that WP chose to implement.

Even so, there is one thing that can help with speed -- change the indexes in `wp_postmeta`.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta for details.

`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` also adds some cost to the query.  Maybe you can do without "... out of nnn"?

Comment: Thank you - answer appreciated.  -Nick